# Specflow is not executing tests in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, specflow

I have a very weird behavior with Specflow that only applies to one team member. Everyone else have no issue what so ever.

The VS2019 testrunner is correctly displaying all specflow tests, but when "Running all tests" none of the tests gets executed but have the information "no source available". Specflow is generating all cs files correctly.

I tried to create a completly new solution with one unit test project in it, added specflow to it, created a feature, generated the steps and run all tests. Everything worked as expected, the test was executed and was successful. Then I added this new csproj to the other solution where the tests are not exectued. Strangly the "new test" didn't work in the old solution either.

When someone else of the project team is cloning our repository, installing specflow everything works fine for them. It is only this one machine in this one solution. I already tried to reinstall VS2019. We checked that every project in the solution has the same target platform, we tried to delete some %TEMP% files but nothing worked so far.

NuGet packages:

- SpecFlow v3.0.225
- SpecFlow.MsTest v3.0.225
- SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation v3.0.225

Comment: Which version of SpecFlow do you have installed, and which NuGet packages have you installed on that test project?

Comment: We are using the nuget package of specflow with version 3.0.225 and SpecFlow.MsTest and SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation with the same version numbers. The VS integration is the latest version for VS2019. The weird thing is, that in another project on his machine everything is working fine, it is not working for one specific solution.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the `.vs` folder in the solution? Those are a bunch of Visual Studio temp files as well.

Comment: I actually had this same exact problem with an old unit test project, but recreating the project fixed it for me. You essentially tried that, and it still didn't work. Does this person have any uncommitted changes to the `.sln` or `.csproj` files? Maybe try deleting the existing clone and re-cloning?

Comment: I tried deleting the .vs folder with no effect. No uncommitted changes, same branch as everyone else. I may try to delete the csproj and re-add all files and see if this works.

Comment: Have you managed to make it work?

Comment: @MarekM. sadly not. The only new thing I know is that this happens only with Visual Studio 2019 v16.2 or newer. With v16.1 everything works fine.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue as you with:

- VS 2019 v16.6.2
- SpecFlow v3.30.2
- SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation v3.3.30
- SpecRun.Runner v3.3.14
- SpecRun.Specflow.3-3-0 v3.3.14
- MSTest.TestAdapter v2.1.2
- MSTest.TestFramework v2.1.2

I tried many tricks from this forum and Github SpecFlow support and none worked.
When I looked at the log file, on the *TestResults* folder, I saw something interesting:

[image]

I basically logged on that link (with the same account that is logged in VS) and the tests start to run.

Hope that solves your business mate. I know these things drives anyone mad.

Comment: It's like they don't want you to use SpecFlow.  Why hide this message in a hidden text file with no indication that you should read it?

Comment: Very good! Remembering that the logs folder is named 'TestResults'

Comment: Where's the log file?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with a SpecFlow Project using MSTest as unit test provider, the tests were visible in the Test-Explorer but running them had no effect. I was able to solve my problem by installing the NuGet package *MSTest.TestFramework*.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, find the .sln where the acceptance tests reside and delete the contents of the bin folder completely.  Rebuild your solution and run your acceptance tests.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in VS 2022 using .NET 6. I managed to get it working for NUnit with the following Nuget packages.

```
    <PackageReference Include="FluentAssertions" Version="6.8.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.3.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.13.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="4.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.Support" Version="4.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver" Version="4.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow" Version="3.9.74" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.NUnit" Version="3.9.74" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.Plus.LivingDocPlugin" Version="3.9.57" />
```

Note the key package to get the tests to actually run in the Test Exlporer was

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.3.2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR:

- In VS, raise "test logging level" to *Trace*; then view detailed "Tests" output in the Output Window.
- Or run tests from CLI with `dotnet test`.

Both give you more detailed logging, which will show the specific problem.

## Raise test logging level

You can raise test log verbosity in Visual Studio.

<kbd>CTRL+Q</kbd> -> "test logging level" -> open -> set to *Trace*.
This is equivalent to Tools -> Options -> Test -> General -> Logging level -> set to *Trace*.

Then your Output Window will have detailed information.
Run the test.
Open the Output window and use the drop-down to view output from "Tests".
The logging is now detailed.

For example, I discovered that I was targetting an SDK that I don't have installed:

> ========== Starting test discovery ========== Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestPlatformException:
> Testhost process for source(s)
> 'C:(...)\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\MyProject.dll' exited with error:
> You must install or update .NET to run this application. (...)

- Open the menu **Test > Options**.
  This opens the Options window with the Test > General tab selected.
- In the *Logging* section,
  raise the **logging level** from *Informational (default)* to *Diagnostic* or even ***Trace***.

## Or run tests from CLI

You can also run the tests from a console.

Navigate to the solution or project folder, then run `dotnet test`.

You will get detailed output.